# My login routine in my app is not directing me to the main form

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am building a Windows form application using VS2010. I want to read the userid and password and check their validity with the database. If a proper match is found, I want to direct the user to the main form. My code is currently not directing when I enter the proper credentials. What might be the cause?

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=HMS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Developer;Password=abc@123";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

string SelectStatement = "SELECT * FROM Users where UserID = '@UserID' and Password = '@password'";
SqlCommand insertcommand = new SqlCommand(SelectStatement, connection);
insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", textBox1.Text);
insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);
SqlDataReader reader;

try
{
  connection.Open();
  reader = insertcommand.ExecuteReader();

  while (reader.Read())
  {
    string userid = reader["UserID"].ToString();
    string pass = reader["Password"].ToString();
    if (userid == textBox1.Text.ToString() && pass == textBox2.Text.ToString()) // login successful
    {
      Mainform main = new Mainform();
      this.Hide();
      main.Show();
    }
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password!");
    }
  }//end while
  reader.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  throw ex;

}//end catch
finally
{
  connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do not store the password as raw text in the database.  That is just asking for trouble.  You should store a salted hash in the database and compute the hash in the client and compare those.

Second, try main.ShowDialog() to get your main form to stay up.

Comment: Let's focus on one problem at a time. For all intents and purposes, storing the password as raw text could be fine. Yes, we shouldn't do it, but that wasn't really the question.

Comment: i understand the risk involved in saving password in plain text.

Comment: this is the linking format i using to link to other forms.The login is the only problem

Comment: I tried main.ShowDialog(), but the same problem persist.Besides after changing the SqlException to Exception no changes

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your if and walk through the code from there.  Maybe there is something in the Form_Load or other method causing problems.

Comment: The problem was in the select query:'@UserID' instead of@UserID